# Фразеологические обороты в роли сравнительных

Tags: пунктуация

...Обособляются ли они, если определяемое слово не входит в состав фразеологизма? Интересующий меня контекст: "Парламентарии — сбор блатных и нищих, столь же безынициативных, сколь и царь, — не нашлись что возразить и разбрелись по домам (,) как побитые собаки".

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Не  подскажете,  откуда  цитата.

Comment: Плод моего литературного труда [с древа познания][1].


  [1]: http://ficbook.net/readfic/2097464

Answer (score 3, accepted):

КАК РЕШАЮТСЯ ПОДОБНЫЕ ЗАДАЧИ

Устойчивый  оборот "как побитая собака" имеет значение "приниженно, униженно, трусливо", то есть потребляется в значении наречия.

В большинстве случаев оборот обособляется,  но обособление связано не с правилом "это фразеологизм или часть фразеологизма", а с особой структурой тех предложений, в которых он используется в качестве обособленного обстоятельства образа действия, например:

"Я смотрел на нее, как побитая собака, и не знал, что сказать". "Дырка ужасно перетрусил и начал скулить, как побитая собака". "Любезный молодой человек съежился, как побитая собака, и исчез".  В то же время оборот может не обособляться, если тесно связан со сказуемым или входит в основное сообщение, например: "Вы, которая тут козыряет спесью семи цариц, а на встрече сидит как побитая собака".

Также для сравнения: "Наутро, как убитые, заснули мужики". - "А Иван, кряхтя, полез под дубовое корыто и лежит там как убитый". Обособление оборота зависит от его позиции в предложении.

РЕШЕНИЕ ДАННОЙ ЗАДАЧИ

(1)Если поставить запятую, все подумают, что это правильно: оборот, действительно, чаще всего обособляется.

(2) В  то же время при обособлении получается нечеткая интонационная картина, при которой фраза "не нашлись что возразить и разбрелись по домам" противопоставлена фразе "как побитые собаки". Но ведь оборот относится к глаголу "разбрелись", поэтому желательно не делать между ними паузу, то есть не обособлять его.

(3)Есть еще решение:"Парламентарии - сбор блатных и нищих, столь же безынициативных, сколь и царь, - не нашлись что возразить и, как побитые собаки, разбрелись по домам. В этом случае обособление обязательно в силу его позиции в предложении, а оборот относится ко втором сказуемому.

Comment: Очень обстоятельно, исчерпывающе. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Фразеологические обороты с компонентом сравнения не выделяются запятыми. Ср.:  У льва как гору с плеч свалило (Крылов);,  Молодые супруги были счастливы, и жизнь их текла как по маслу (Чехов).Но в данном конкретном случае указанная запятая нужна, т.к. фразеологизмом является " как побитая собака" , а не "разбрелись по домам как побитые собаки". Если фраза " разбрелись по домам " входила бы в состав фразеологизма и являлась бы частью фразеологизма, то запятая не требовалась.

София, если не поставить запятую, то получится , что глагол  "разбрелись" входит в состав фразеологического оборота, что, и Вы прекрасно знаете, не так. Кстати, и Грамма.ру тоже настаивает о употреблении запятой в этом примере.

Уважаемая София. Я с вами полностью согласен. Но я не имею в виду, что от постановки запятой появляется фразеологический оборот. Я лишь говорю, что нужна запятая поскольку  "как побитые собаки"  - сравнительный оборот перед которым нужна запятая.

Comment: Серж, здесь дело не в том, что у фразеологического оборота особый статус: вот не поставили запятую и получился фразеологизм, а это вовсе не фразеологизм. Не теория фразеологизмов должна управлять теорией синтаксиса, а наоборот, так как синтаксис - это старшая структура, ей должно быть всё подчинено. А в синтаксисе фразеологический оборот - это устойчивое словосочетание со значением одного слова, и он должен не диктовать свои правила, а исполнять там определенные функции, выступать в роли обстоятельства (обособленного или необособленного).

Comment: Фразеологизм - это материал, из которого автор строит предложение так, как ему это удобно, меняя структуру и объем предложения: Они разбрелись  как побитые собаки. - Они , как побитые собаки, разбрелись по домам.